# Can webpack be set up to update/keep track of changed yarn packages?

Tags: webpack, version-control, yarnpkg

I use yarn as my package manager. I use webpack as my code bundler.

When I upgrade a package with yarn, I (obviously) don't push the package's source code. If a colleague pulls and doesn't run **yarn install --flags**, they might end up building the webpack bundles with outdated packages.

So my question is... can webpack be set up to keep track through Yarn of updated packages? I could always just tell my colleagues to update the packages, but that increases the chance for mistakes by too much for my taste.

I am aware of the webpack-shell-plugin but it's an imperfect solution. I have it set up to run the commands to update yarn packages before the build happens.

However, the first time the webpack command is run, it updates the packages but doesn't actually build with them. They are used at the following webpack build. This, of course, can be misleading and can cause a number of other problems.

Production/dev separation of build environments are not an option due to other issues which are irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Why not just have `npm update` as a `post-checkout` git hook?

Comment: Didn't think of that.